# Incorrect datetime value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 - (Ubuntu)
```

Here's how the table was created:

```
CREATE TABLE `full_contact_uploads` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `likelihood` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'active',
  `batch` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `requestId` varchar(48) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `processed_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE `full_contact_uploads`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `text` (`text`);


ALTER TABLE `full_contact_uploads`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

However, if I do something like this:

```
UPDATE `full_contact_uploads` SET `likelihood` = '0.9', `requestId` = '194590cf-6ea9-426d-aa72-9ba25bdb1979', `status` = 'processed', `processed_at` = '09-01-2016 22:21:58' WHERE `id` = '2'
```

I get the following error message:

```
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '09-01-2016 22:21:58' for column 'processed_at' at row 1
```

I believe this to be the correct time format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql [always expects date components](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html) to be ordered as per ISO 8601, i.e. yyyy[-]mm[-]dd